# How does the dio package in flutter joins the base-url with url and apikey

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dio

How does the dio package in flutter joins the base-url with url and apikey in this code. Iam bit confused with the working of dio package can somebody please help me

If I have a URL of this kind

```
const req = unirest("GET", "https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/list");

"X-RapidAPI-Host": "tasty.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "f2c5e7c653mshbc6a7a174c0cda1p1d46c4jsna9d84f0c1681",
    "useQueryString": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of making HTTP requests using DIO package:

```
class Api {
  BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: "your_base_url",
  connectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
  receiveTimeout: 30 * 1000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '....',
    'useQueryString': true
  },
 );

  Dio getDio() {
    return Dio(options);
  }

    Future<dynamic> getRequest(Map<String, String> params) async {
    var result;
    params['query'] = 'abc'
    try {
      Dio dio = getDio();
      result = await dio.get('/url-path', queryParameters: params);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    if (result != null) {
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```